# Jenkinsfile docker documentation

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to get the Jenkinsfile `docker` object documentation with all the possible methods it has. The below site has some examples and does not seem to have the complete list of methods.

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get detailed information on available methods, open the Pipeline Syntax available on any Pipeline Job page:
[image]

This functionality is implemented trough docker-workflow plugin.

More info and usage examples here:
https://go.cloudbees.com/docs/plugins/docker-workflow/